# FitText not resize the fonts contained between <a> and </ a>?

Tags: jquery-plugins

[FitText](http://fittextjs.com/) functions normally in the titles and paragraphs, but does not work on the links `(<a> href ... </ a>)`.

Please, any tips?

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into the question.  Post an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved as follows (example):

**CSS**:

```
.content_options {
   width:95%;
   position:absolute;
   top:8%;
   left:0;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="content_options">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="Option 1"><p class="fittext5">Option 1</p></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Option 2"><p class="fittext5">Option 2</p></a></li>
   <ul>
</div><!-- content_options -->
```